# Using Intelli-j maven dependency not resolving

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, model-view-controller

Intelli-j maven dependency not resolving IDE taking java 11 JDK while the jars were imported by running on command prompt by setting java 8 path.Is this root cause that dependency not resolving?

Any suggestion shall be helpful

Comment: Could you please ad more information and screenshots to clarify the issue?

Comment: Hi actually maven dependency have been fetched from central repository and shown in m2 repository but dependency are not resolving in files intelli-j 2020.3 version and maven using 3.6.1 the jdk version is 1.8.It is a Multimodule project

Comment: So, you have red code showing "Cannot resolve" even needed dependencies are mention in pom and listed under "External Dependencies" node in Project Tree?

Comment: yes you are right correct The same thing is happening,can you suggest anything

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Settings/Preferences dialog Ctrl+Alt+S, go to Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler.
2. On the page that opens, check if the Project bytecode version and Target bytecode version match, or leave the Target bytecode version option blank so it can be determined from JDK.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the version of maven configured in intellij idea, in my case I followed the following steps to use the most recent version of maven.

1. From the main menu select File | Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment |Build Tools | Maven.
2. On the Maven settings page, in the Maven home directory field, specify the location of the Maven custom version installation. For the Maven wrapper, select the use Maven wrapper option from the list. In this case the version of Maven defined in the .mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties file will be used.

[Add maven local to IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UctAt.png)